# How to capture non browser calls with Fiddler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fiddler

I have a local website that calls several WCF services on other servers.  When I hit a page on the site that I know will call services on other servers, the only thing showing up in Fiddler is localhost.  Is there a way to see all of the service calls?

Comment: Try [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).